# Eigenvalues that are functions

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, terminology, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let us have the Laplacian on a compact manifold $M$. Suppose I have some equation of the form
$$-\Delta u(x) = f(x)u(x).$$
If $f \equiv c$ were a constant, this would be an eigenvalue problem involving the Laplacian. But if $f$ is a function what kind of problem is this? What is it called? Is it well-studied?

Comment: Look for weighted eigenvalue problems.

Comment: If you're given $f(x)$, it's still an eigenvalue problem but with respect to the operator $L=\Delta+f(x)$ i.e. $Lu(x)=0$.

Comment: @Semiclassical I did think that however then it just becomes an operator equation. I thought more structure would be good.